# Slickgrid is rendered until the width of some of its columns is adjusted

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, slickgrid

I am trying to show the contents of a table in a slickgrid which is displayed in a dialog. It is working incorrectly: When I open the dialog, the grid only shows the headers of the grid and the pagination controls:

[image]

I can change the page and the grid is not rendered. I can only make it renderize by adjusting the width of any column, I do not know what event triggers the column adjustment and I would like to invoke it manually:

[image]

The div that i use as a grid container and which I open in a dialog:

```
<div id="dlgBitacoraCnfGlobal" style="display:none;">
    <div id="divContenedor" style="width: 100%; height: 95%; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; clear: both;">
        <div id="divBotones" class="toolBarBox" style="padding-top: 5px; float: left;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><s:message code="general.formatoFecha" />:</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="fechaInicial"><s:message code="general.fechaInicial.desde" />&nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fechaInicial" size="10" maxlength="10"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <label for="fechaFinal"><s:message code="general.fechaFinal.a"/>&nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fechaFinal" size="10" maxlength="10"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <span id="toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
            <aclutil:secBtn pantalla="${nombrePantalla}" domId="btnRefrescar" seguro="false" mensaje="${refres}" />
        </span>
        <div id="divPagerBitacora" style="margin: 5px; clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="divGridBitacora" style="width: 95%; height: 420px; margin: 10px; margin-top: 5px; "></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript functions with which I create and control the grid:

```
function initComponents() {
    $('#bitacora', $ctxt).button({
        icons : {
            primary : "ui-icon-clock"
        }
    }).click(function() {
        buscarBitacora();
    });

    initBitacora($ctxt);
}

function consultarBitacoraTab() {
    cargaInicial();
}

function buscarBitacora() {
    var $dialogoBitacora = $("#dlgBitacoraCnfGlobal", $ctxt);
    $dialogoBitacora.dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        height : 700,
        width : 1100,
        title : "Bitacora de cambios",
        open : function(event, ui) {
            consultarBitacoraTab();
        },
        close : function(event, ui) {
        },
        buttons : [ {
            text : "Aceptar",
            click : function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.dialog("close");
            }
        } ]
    });
    $dialogoBitacora.dialog("open");
}

function initBitacora($ctxt) {
    $context = $ctxt;
    self = this;
    _fechaInicial = $("#fechaInicial", $ctxt);
    $(_fechaInicial).attr("id", $(_fechaInicial).attr("id") + "_" + _id);
    _fechaFinal = $("#fechaFinal", $ctxt);
    $(_fechaFinal).attr("id", $(_fechaFinal).attr("id") + "_" + _id);
    crearDatePicker();
    var preparar = function () {
        $(":button", $context).button();
        $divGridBitacora = $('#divGridBitacora', $ctxt);
        $divPagerBitacora= $('#divPagerBitacora', $ctxt);
        $btnRefrescar = $("#btnRefrescar", $context);
        $btnRefrescar.click(cargaInicial);
    };

    return $.when(preparar()).done(function () {
        crearGridListado();
        cargaInicial();
    });

    function crearGridListado() {
        var columnas = [];
        var opciones = {
            editable: false,
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            asyncEditorLoading: true,
            autoEdit: false,
            enableAddRow: false,
            forceFitColumns: false,
            enableRowReordering: true,
            rowHeight: 25,
            gridName: "bitacora_configuracion_global",
            enableSearchStringMap: true,
            sortable: true
        };
        fnDescribirGrid({
            url: "/describir/nombrePojo/BitacoraConfiguracionVO/",
            columnas: columnas,
            columnasOmitir: [""],
            callback: function () {
                rgListado = new RemoteGridFactory({
                    divGrid: $divGridBitacora,
                    divPager: $divPagerBitacora,
                    options: opciones,
                    columns: columnas,
                    pagingOptions: {
                        pageSize: tamanoPagina,
                        pagenum: 0
                    },
                    onRunFilter: cargaInicial,
                    onSort: cargaInicial,
                    listarPag:cargarBitacora,
                    onDblClick: function (e, row, cell) {
                        var item = dataViewBitacora.rows[row];
                        creaMensaje({mensaje: item.valor, cssClass: "cell-click",titulo: "Bitacora de cambios", contexto: $ctxt});
                    },
                    onSelectedRowsChanged: function () {
                        var rows = gridBitacora.getSelectedRows();
                        itemSeleccionado = dataViewBitacora.rows[rows[0]];
                    }
                });

                gridBitacora = rgListado.getGrid();
                dataViewBitacora = rgListado.getDataView();
                mapaDeBusqueda = rgListado.getSearchMap();
                paginadorListado = rgListado.getPager();
            }
        });
    }
}


function cargaInicial() {
    var datosConsultados = [];
    datosPagina0 = consultarBitacora(paginaInicial, function(resultado) {
        datosConsultados = resultado.pageItems[1];
        totalNumeroListado = resultado.rowsCount;
    });
    $.when(datosPagina0).done(function() {
        $('#divBotones', $context).unblock();
        if (datosConsultados.length === 0) {
            dataViewBitacora.setItems([], paginaInicial);
            return;
        }
        dataViewBitacora.setItems(datosConsultados, totalNumeroListado);
        gridBitacora.render();
    });
}

function cargarBitacora(pagina) {
    paginadorListado.lock();
    paginadorListado.updateButtons();
    consultarBitacora(pagina, function(resultado) {
        dataViewBitacora.addItems([], pagina);
        dataViewBitacora.addItems(resultado.pageItems[1], pagina);
        paginadorListado.unlock();
        paginadorListado.updateButtons();
        $('#divBotones', $context).unblock();
    });
}

function consultarBitacora(pagina, callback) {
    $('#divBotones', $context).block();
    if (!pagina)
        pagina = paginaInicial;
    var parametrosBusqueda = {
        '@class' : JacksonHelper.HASHMAP,
        filtros : mapaDeBusqueda,
        orden : rgListado.getOrderMap(),
        first : pagina * tamanoPagina,
        page : pagina,
        max : tamanoPagina,
        cadenaBuscada : _cadenaBuscada
    };
    return $.postJSON('/bitacoraHistory/search?fInicial='
            + _fechaInicial.datepicker("getDate").getTime() + "&fFinal="
            + _fechaFinal.datepicker("getDate").getTime(), parametrosBusqueda,
            callback);
}
```

My main objective is to understand why the grid is generated until I adjust the width of some of its columns, if I can apply a "patch" like trigger the same event that is triggered when I do the column adjustment but manually correct this error. I am attentive to any suggestion to understand and solve the problem

Comment: The problem is the css propertie display:none.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking ... are you using the 6pac repo (https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid)? The MLeibman original repo is unmaintained and quite old now. You can get this behaviour with the MLeibman repo, for example, if the div is hidden when `init` is run. The 6pac repo contains *many* fixes and enhancements, as well as working with new versions of jQuery.